# My mp3 links are downloaded instead of being streamed on my web player

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a mp3 web player on my local web server (OpenWrt), the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="music.css">
    <script src="music.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">
        Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="active"><a href="music1.mp3">Music 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="music2.mp3">Music 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="music3.mp3">Music 3</a></li>


    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

They always get captured by my IDM whenever I click the song titles, I don't want to download the songs, I just want to stream them. How do I solve this?

My javascript:

```
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .10;
    audio[0].play();
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
```

**UPDATE:** Guys I got the script from http://jsfiddle.net/WsXX3/33/ what's weird is that when I click the song titles in `jsfiddle` it plays the song but when I implement the codes on my own web server it downloads the song. How should I implement the script?

**@gratz** I did what you suggested but still doesn't solve the problem, here's my complete script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#playlist,audio{background:#666;width:400px;padding:20px;}
.active a{color:#5DB0E6;text-decoration:none;}
li a{color:#eeeedd;background:#333;padding:5px;display:block;}
li a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

$(document).ready(function() {
  init();
});
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .10;
    audio[0].play();
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">
        Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">Ravel Bolero</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3">Moonlight Sonata - Beethoven</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3">Canon in D Pachabel</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph_vbr_mp3.zip">patrikbkarl chamber symph</a></li>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.nunzioweb.com/streaming_audio-example.htm   You have to create a playlist, then use that playlist as your src in the audio element.

Comment: Is there some JavaScript to go with this? Otherwise you're just clicking on links to files <a href="filename">link</a> which will do what you have said.

Comment: @gratz, no is the problem about htaccess or something, I just updated my javascript, please check out my updated post.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script appears to be failing because you're calling init() before the DOM has been loaded so the elements you're referencing don't exist. If you look at the console, you get an error similar to this: "Cannot set property 'volume' of undefined" because the audio element isn't there when init() is called.
It looks as though you're using jQuery so changing the 'init();' line to this should help:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  init();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't solve the problem, please check out the complete script on my post.

Comment: Can you implement the script above on your own web server and see what happens?

Comment: You're writing jquery code but not pulling in the jquery library.

Comment: Can you please update your post with what I should write? I'm sorry I still don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Edited your update in the question which included the code based on my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend for a link to go somewhere, then don't make it a link.

Instead, use a `<button type="button">`. "Button" buttons do things on the current page. You can do something like `<button type="button" data-song="music1.mp3">` and get the `.data('song')` of the button that has been clicked.

With this setup, it will either work or - if there's an error in your JavaScript - not do anything. But at least it won't do things you specifically don't want.

Comment: Falling back to a plain link is pretty good behaviour when JS hits a failure state in this case though. The problem should be solved by fixing the errors in the script, not throwing away progressive enhancement.

Comment: Please check out the update on my post :D I got the script from jsfiddle, and I think I just don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are two issues. First of all, I can't see you fetching jQuery at all. So unless you omitted this in your example, this is something that should be done.

Just add this to your HTML (this uses the same jQuery version as in the jsfiddle example (you should consider if you should use a more updated version of jQuery) ):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script src="music.js"></script>
```

The second is, like grats suggested, that you should not call init() before the DOM has been loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    init();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <audio controls>
      <source src="vincent.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
      <source src="vincent.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/OriginalMusicPlayer.swf" width="225" height="86">
       <param name="movie" value="media/OriginalMusicPlayer.swf"/>
       <param name="FlashVars" value="mediaPath=vincent.mp3" />
      </object>
    </audio>
```

You can also play with buttons :)

```
<audio id="player" src="vincent.mp3"></audio>
<div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume += 0.1">Vol+ </button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.1">Vol- </button>
</div>
```

Comment: ... How does this help?

Comment: @Dhru, when I play with buttons, it works but when I click the song titles it doesn't, I want to play the songs by clicking the titles, is there a better solution ? Thanks for the answer :D

Comment: !) try with disable the IDM and which browser u work ?

Comment: Please check out the update on my post :D I got the script from jsfiddle, and I think I just don't know how to implement it.